# S3 static website with custom domain giving "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Tags: amazon-route53

I am almost new to AWS but have some therotical knowledge. As a small experiment i created a simple html website and add the files on S3 bucket and enabled static website. Worked pretty well using the S3 link, the HTML content was visible.

Next i registered a domain with Route 53 and created an "A" record pointing to bucket where html files exist, also registered subdomain bucket and corresponding "A" record.
When i hit the domain now, it say's "DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN". Checked bucket permission and policy, all looks fine as per AWS documentation. Test record returns "NOERROR" and UDP protocol with random IP.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I had also posted the same question in AWS developer forums, below is the solution:

The new registered domain needed an update for the name servers which were present in NS records. I copied the Name servers from NS records and updated "Nameserver" in registered domain and within minutes my Domain was responding with static website hosted on S3.

What i didnt understood is , why aws doesnt automatically update the name servers for registered domain. That obviously could have saved some time and frustration for me and many others i guess.

Thanks